# Install homebrew mac os x for xampp

Tags: xampp, homebrew, mamp

A month ago I installed hombrew and pystuff to use python on my mac. Since then I've been doing more database oriented programming ie mysql and php. Long story short; I was trying to run xampp command stuff from the terminal but it wasn't working so I deduced that my installation paths for xampp (mamp) wasn't valid. I have since uninstalled xampp and tried installing with home-brew via this link: http://www.threeeyedbird.com/blog/2013/06/11/setting-up-a-local-dev-environment-with-homebrew/

The first line of installation;

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

yielded a result that told me the link was invalid so I;

```
brew ls
```

to make sure home-brew was already installed, and it was...

I have since uninstalled home-brew in this link 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/how-to-cleanly-remove-homebrew

Now when I type:

```
brew ls
```

It says command not found which is good because i wanted to uninstall everything completely...

I want to install home-brew in the proprietary paths that would make for a great local developing environment i.e.; all the command line short cuts work, all the paths are correct etc

The only problem now when I enter the first line of the home-brew install for a fresh start (which installs home-brew): ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

The terminal tells me the link is invalid. and i get a bad request 400 error

How can I download home-brew perfectly all things considered?

Answer (score 0):

This was the link that didn't work

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

I just installed it using this link from the home-brew web page

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```